# Problems Removing Subview from SuperView - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, view, uigesturerecognizer, subview

Not sure why this isn't working to remove the added subview from the parent view. I want it to be removed if the longpress action is ended. I tested with an NSLog and I know that the gestures are properly registering as ended, but it's not removing the subview.

```
-(void)addSubview:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"overlayView" owner:self     options:nil];
    UIView *subView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        [self.view addSubview:subView];
        }
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [subView removeFromSuperview];
        }    
}
```

### Desired functionality:

longpress starts: add subview. 
longpress ends: remove subview.

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint on the line [subView removeFromSuperview] just to check which view is there, make sure it is not nil. The only reason I can see for this not to work is you are not getting a reference to the correct view or to any view at all.

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't getting the right superview, but I'm not sure how to specifically call it. Maybe I'm not adding the superview properly?

Comment: Looking at other peoples answers, they've got it sussed when they say you don't have a reference to the subview. I'd go with @Utkarsh Goel's answer, that seems to be along the right lines

Answer (score 5):

I hope you will resolve the issue by declaring UIView *subview in .h file and then putting below lines in viewDidLoad:

```
 NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"overlayView" owner:self     options:nil];
    UIView *subView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

and then:

```
-(void)addSubview:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        [self.view addSubview:subView];
        }
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [subView removeFromSuperview];
        }    
}
```

Comment: Worked! Was the issue that I was recreating the view every time an gesture event was fired?

Comment: Yup, thats what @Wain mentioned. If you are going to load new instances of views, the reference to the one that is on screen is lost, so it won't be removed simple as that.